# The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add

Tags: asp.net, database, oledb

This is odd because I'm not inserting data, I'm pulling data with a query.

I'm trying to run

```
SELECT DISTINCT description FROM products;
```

Which outputs the error "The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add.".

However, running the following doesn't produce the error:

```
SELECT description FROM products;
```

So I'm confused as to what the issue would be.

I'm using OleDbDataReader and taking data out of an mdb database file.

Comment: This might be related to: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896950/us

Comment: Looks like that is what the problem is.  I'll have to make a workaround.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be related to: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896950/us

> This problem occurs because when you
>   set the UniqueValues query property to
>   Yes, a DISTINCT keyword is added to
>   the resulting SQL statement. The
>   DISTINCT keyword directs Access to
>   perform a comparison between records.
>   When Access performs a comparison
>   between two Memo fields, Access treats
>   the fields as Text fields that have a
>   255-character limit. Sometimes Memo
>   field data that is larger than 255
>   characters will generate the error
>   message that is mentioned in the
>   "Symptoms" section. Sometimes only 255
>   characters are returned from the Memo
>   field.

Workaround:

> To work around this problem, modify
>   the original query by removing the
>   Memo field. Then, create a second
>   query that is based on both the table
>   and the original query. This new query
>   uses all the fields from the original
>   query, and this new query uses the
>   Memo field from the table. When you
>   run the second query, the first query
>   runs. Then, this data is used to run
>   the second query. This behavior
>   returns the Memo field data based on
>   the returned data of the first query.

Comment: Although I was too lazy to use that workaround, this was the problem. Instead, I just selected the field and kept track of duplicates with a hashtable.